# search and replace for forward slash

Tags: vim

I am trying to replace multiple forward slashes "//" with a single slash "/".

How would you do that?

Also, How would you replace "asd/qwe/zxc" with "fgh/vbn"?

I was able to do this half way using below. But how do I use forward slash in the search string or the replace string.

```
:%s/asd.qwe.zxc/fgh/g
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either escape it or use different delimiters.

```
:s/\/\//\//g
:s#//#/#g
```

I prefer the latter.

Missed the second part:

```
:s/asd\/qwe\/zxc/fgh\/vbn/g
:s@asd/qwe/zxc@fgh/vbn@g
```

You can pick any delimiter that you want in the same manner that you could in `ed` or `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using:

```
:%s/\/\//\//g
```

to replace all double slashes with single slashes (though I imagine a guru will show a much cooler way shortly :) ). The general idea is that you need to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Esc :`

`:1,$s/asd\/qwe\/zxc/fgh\/vbn/g`

You need to escape '/' using backslash '\' .

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\/\//\#/gc
```

It replaces OpenSCAD comment (//) to Python comment (#).

```
    // Faces: 60
    F = [
        [ 0,  1,  2], //  0
        [ 1,  3,  4], //  1
        [ 1,  4,  2], //  2
        [ 2,  4,  5], //  3
        [ 0,  2,  6], //  4

    # Faces: 60
    F = [
        [ 0,  1,  2], #  0
        [ 1,  3,  4], #  1
        [ 1,  4,  2], #  2
        [ 2,  4,  5], #  3
        [ 0,  2,  6], #  4
```